# Is there a way to reload my JFrame game other than using setVisible() to true and false?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So the goal here is essentially to create a basic text-based roguelike game. I'm fairly new to java, so I'm sure you'll find tons of stuff to be improved with my program. The biggest thing I have is I don't know of a good way to update the screen so it accurately displays the player's position. What I am currently using is `setVisible(false)` and `setVisible(true)` to completely reload the program, which is fine for now for the purposes of development and at least ensuring things are working. However, the time has come for where that no longer does what I need it, so my question is essentially how do I reload it each time an arrow key is pressed (that's the input for moving the player).

I have experimented with repaint() with nothing to show for it as I could not get it to do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code as it is:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DisplayGraphics extends Canvas{  
    // Global game variables
    int screenW = 1024;
    int screenH = 768;

    static JFrame f = null;
    static int playerX = 0;
    static int playerY = 0;
    static String[][] map = new String[80][36];


//  public void makeMap(String[][] map) {
//      
//  }

    
    public void paint(Graphics g) {  
        for (int x=0;x<map.length;x++) {
            for (int y=0;y<map[x].length;y++) {
                if (x==playerX&& y==playerY) map[x][y] = "@";
                else map[x][y] = ".";
            }
        }
        for (int x=0;x<map.length;x++) {
            for (int y=0;y<map[x].length;y++) {
                g.drawString(map[x][y], (11+(8*x)), (13*y)+14);
            }
        }

        g.drawString("HEALTH:", 10, 545);
    }  
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        // DEFINE PLAYER VARIABLES 
        DisplayGraphics m=new DisplayGraphics();  
        f=new JFrame();  
        f.add(m);  
        f.setSize(840,610);

        
        //we get the keyboard input
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    System.out.println("Up Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                    playerY--;
                    System.out.println(playerY);
                    f.setVisible(false);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    System.out.println("Down Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                    playerY++;
                    System.out.println(playerY);
                    f.setVisible(false);
                    f.setVisible(true); }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    System.out.println("Left Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                    playerX--;
                    System.out.println(playerX);
                    f.setVisible(false);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    System.out.println("Right Arrrow-Key is pressed!");
                    playerX++;
                    System.out.println(playerX);
                    f.setVisible(false);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        f.setVisible(true); 
    }
    
    public void actionPerformed(KeyEvent event) {
        f.repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create code by guessing, which will lead to frustration. If you're going to use the Swing GUI library, I know of no short-cuts to learning to use it well, and the best place to learn it is through the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).

Comment: As for your code, my own recommendation is to scrap it and start over. Most of that code needs to be outside of the main method or any static method and into proper OOP-complaint classes with private instance and public methods, code that follows basic Java OOPs practices. The main method should only create your main objects and set them running, and that's it. If you're not yet familiar with these, then best to hold off on GUI coding and first learn these principles.

Answer (score 1):

Your code produced an interesting game field.  I'm impressed that you're just learning.

I took your idea and created the following GUI.

[image: Display Graphics]

I started the player in the center of the map.  I'm representing the player as a blue circle.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

The first thing I did was create a game model.  I made the map a `java.awt.Dimension` specifying the width and height of the map.  The drawing `JPanel` dimensions are based on the map dimensions.  I specified the player position with a `java.awt.Point`, which holds an X and Y `int`.

You can add one or more monsters or obstacles the same way, by defining them as a `Point`.

Next, I created the `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.  I used key bindings rather than a key listener.  Yes, the code looks more complicated.  The advantage is that key bindings continue to work when the drawing `JPanel` doesn't have focus.  I added the WASD keys as a bonus.

Drawing the player is a rather simple math equation.  I draw the circle based on the center point, so I have to adjust the drawing coordinates in the `drawOval`.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.  You should separate the classes into different files.  Good luck expanding your game.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DisplayGraphics implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DisplayGraphics());
    }

    private final DisplayModel model;

    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    public DisplayGraphics() {
        this.model = new DisplayModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Graphics");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final int playerWidth, margin;

        private final DisplayModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(DisplayModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.margin = 10;
            this.playerWidth = 16;
            int totalWidth = 2 * margin + (model.getMap().width + 1) * playerWidth;
            int totalHeight = 2 * margin + (model.getMap().height + 1) * playerWidth;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(totalWidth, totalHeight));
            setKeyBindings();
        }

        private void setKeyBindings() {
            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");

            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "up");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "down");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "left");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "right");

            actionMap.put("up", new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    model.incrementPlayerPositionY(-1);
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            actionMap.put("down", new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    model.incrementPlayerPositionY(+1);
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            actionMap.put("left", new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    model.incrementPlayerPositionX(-1);
                    repaint();
                }
            });

            actionMap.put("right", new AbstractAction() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    model.incrementPlayerPositionX(+1);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Point p = model.getPlayerPosition();
            int halfWidth = playerWidth / 2;
            int x = margin + halfWidth + p.x * playerWidth;
            int y = margin + halfWidth + p.y * playerWidth;
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillOval(x - halfWidth, y - halfWidth, playerWidth, playerWidth);
        }

    }

    public class DisplayModel {

        private Point playerPosition;

        private final Dimension map;

        public DisplayModel() {
            this.map = new Dimension(40, 30);
            this.playerPosition = new Point(map.width / 2, map.height / 2);
        }

        public void incrementPlayerPositionX(int increment) {
            playerPosition.x += increment;
            if (playerPosition.x < 0) {
                playerPosition.x = 0;
            }
            if (playerPosition.x > map.width) {
                playerPosition.x = map.width;
            }
        }

        public void incrementPlayerPositionY(int increment) {
            playerPosition.y += increment;
            if (playerPosition.y < 0) {
                playerPosition.y = 0;
            }
            if (playerPosition.y > map.height) {
                playerPosition.y = map.height;
            }
        }

        public Point getPlayerPosition() {
            return playerPosition;
        }

        public Dimension getMap() {
            return map;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I see that we both created our answers at about the same time, both using key bindings. 1+

Answer (score 1):

For example, I would first start with OOP classes, here starting with a Player class, one that holds its own position, a symbol and its own health value, 0 to 100. A simple example could look like so:

```
public class Player {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int health;
    private String symbol;

    public Player() {
        // no-arg constructor if needed
    }
    
    public Player(int x, int y, int health, String symbol) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.health = health;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }
    
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

}
```

This is nothing more than a simple "POJO" or "Plain Old Java Object, one with a few fields, constructors and some getters and setters. Nothing fancy.

I'd create other objects, such as an object to represent the map and any other entities that the map might hold or that the player might interact with. I will dispense with this for now for simplicity, but will show a sample Swing GUI for displaying and changing the location of a Player:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DisplayGraphicsPanel extends JPanel {
    public static final int MAX_X = 80;
    public static final int MAX_Y = 36;
    private static final Dimension CELL_SIZE = new Dimension(15, 17);

    private Player player = new Player(0, 0, 100, "@");
    private JPanel gridHolderPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(MAX_Y, MAX_X, 1, 1));
    private JPanel[][] panelGrid = new JPanel[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
    private JLabel playerLabel;
    private JLabel healthLabel = new JLabel("100%");

    private int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    private InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
    private ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

    public DisplayGraphicsPanel() {
        playerLabel = new JLabel(player.getSymbol());
        gridHolderPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gridHolderPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        for (int y = 0; y < MAX_Y; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < MAX_X; x++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                panel.setPreferredSize(CELL_SIZE);
                panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                panelGrid[y][x] = panel;
                gridHolderPanel.add(panel);
            }
        }
        panelGrid[0][0].add(playerLabel);

        JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
        statusPanel.add(new JLabel("Health:"));
        statusPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        statusPanel.add(healthLabel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gridHolderPanel);
        add(statusPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        putIntoMaps(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), 0, 1);
        putIntoMaps(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), 0, -1);
        putIntoMaps(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), -1, 0);
        putIntoMaps(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), 1, 0);
    }

    private void putIntoMaps(KeyStroke kStroke, int xDir, int yDir) {
        inputMap.put(kStroke, kStroke.toString());
        actionMap.put(kStroke.toString(), new MoveAction(xDir, yDir));
    }

    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {
        private int xDir;
        private int yDir;

        public MoveAction(int xDir, int yDir) {
            this.xDir = xDir;
            this.yDir = yDir;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int playerX = player.getX();
            playerX += xDir;

            // make sure we don't go out of bounds
            playerX = Math.max(0, playerX);
            playerX = Math.min(playerX, MAX_X);
            player.setX(playerX);
            
            int playerY = player.getY();
            playerY += yDir;
            
            playerY = Math.max(0, playerY);
            playerY = Math.min(playerY, MAX_Y);
            player.setY(playerY);
            
            int health = player.getHealth();
            health += Math.random() > 0.5 ? 4 : -4;
            health = Math.min(100, health);
            player.setHealth(health);
            
            healthLabel.setText(String.format("%02d%%", player.getHealth()));

            panelGrid[playerY][playerX].add(playerLabel);
            gridHolderPanel.revalidate();
            gridHolderPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            DisplayGraphicsPanel mainPanel = new DisplayGraphicsPanel();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

This class uses a JPanel that holds a grid of other JPanel cells in a 2D array, and uses [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to capture arrow keystrokes and use them to move the player. Key Bindings are much better to use than a KeyListener, and the tutorial (in the link) will explain it well. Briefly, I have bound each of the arrow keys with an action, one that changes the x or y field of the player object, and then I use those values to move a JLabel that is displayed within the JPanel grid.

Comment: I was trying to teach game design in a short answer.  I hope I didn't overwhelm the OP with too much information.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: yes, you probably did, but not through any fault of your own as I fear that everything will be overwhelming to the OP at this stage. I am hopeful though, that they will sort it all out given time and effort.